# I cannot build the library for feature engineering written by c++

Tags: c++

I tried to build [this library](https://github.com/lacava/feat), but couldn't make it.

[This documentation](https://lacava.github.io/feat/) for the library tells us how to install it.

After I run ./configure file, I run ./install file and got the following error.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libfeat_lib.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/feat_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I made a new [issue](https://github.com/lacava/feat/issues/248)(there is more info for this error), but I cast this question also here to get some solutions.

How should I do to fix this?
Or, could you build this library?

My environment is here:

- Mojave 10.14.6
- Using Anaconda
- Python 3.6.8
- cmake version 3.15.5
- GNU Make 3.81
- Eigen 3.3.4
- Shogun installed by homebrew

Thank you.

Comment: ‘*After I run ./configure file, I run ./install file*’ Shouldn’t you _compile_ something inbetween?

Comment: @Biffen it is what `install` is supposedly doing: https://lacava.github.io/feat/install/

Comment: That’s… just weird. And looking at those scripts they are _very_ weird too. I can’t really help, but I’m not surprised there are issues.

Comment: Maybe, but there is no need according to the doc, as @ypnos mentioned.

Comment: @Biffen yeah, really weird. In github Issue, someone gave me  a solution right now, I'll try that.